# Flutter 2: Cast List<dynamic> into List<Map<String, String>>?

Tags: flutter, dart, casting, dart-null-safety

I am trying to write correctly flutter by precising specific types.

I am collecting data from Json file and try to cast it into a `List<Map<String, String>>`.

```
Future<void> _readJson() async {
    final String response = await rootBundle.loadString('lib/assets/vocabulary.json');
    final data = await json.decode(response);
    print(data);
    _words = List<Map<String, String>>.from(data);
  }
```

However the cast does not works. Even by trying multiple solutions proposed on Stackoverflow, no one is working.

`_words` is of type `List<Map<String, String>>`

Here the output I get actually

```
I/flutter ( 3971): 0
I/flutter ( 3971): [{a: test1, b: test2}, {a: test3, b: test4}, {a: test5, b: test6}]
E/flutter ( 3971): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, String>'
E/flutter ( 3971): #0      new List.from (dart:core-patch/array_patch.dart:40:5)
E/flutter ( 3971): #1      _HomePageState._readJson (package:langage_trainer/pages/home/home_page.dart:108:14)
E/flutter ( 3971): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 3971):
```

Can someone please provide help for casting my data into my _words's type ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the cast, I perform a deep copy of my list using specifiers (as List, as Map<String, String) from the object it returns from the json.decode.

```
Future<void> _readJson() async {
  final String response = await rootBundle.loadString('lib/assets/vocabulary.json');
  final List<Map<String, String>> data = (await json.decode(response) as List)
      .map((e) => e as Map<String, String>).toList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent any subtype errors from rearing its ugly head when working with JSON data, it's best to cast each `Map` element **individually**.

```dart
// Assuming you got this data
List<Map<String, dynamic>> jsonlist = [
  {'foo': 'bar', 'hello': 'world'},
  {'aaa': 'bbb', 'ccc': 'ddd'},
];
print(jsonlist.runtimeType);      // List<Map<String, dynamic>>

// Cast individually
var data = jsonlist.map((item) => item.cast<String, String>()).toList();
print(data.runtimeType);          // List<Map<String, String>>
```

Of course, if your values aren't all Strings like above then working with `Map<String, dynamic>` is your best bet which means you don't have to run `map()`.